# ASP.NET MVC html helper code used to convert model to PropertyName

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This code:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Country.CountryId)
```

gives this output:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Country_CountryId" name="Country.CountryId" />
```

Is there a way to get the id of the above code by using just the model? For eg.

```
@Html.TestBoxFor(model => model.Country.CountryName, new { data_HiddenId= model.Country.CountryId.GetHtmlRenderOrSomething())
```

which should give this:

```
<input type="text" id="Country_CountryName" name="Country.CountryName" data-HiddenId="Country_CountryId" />
```

My main concern is `data-HiddenId`. I want it to be equal to the `id` generated for the `hidden` input above.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Its not the value of the Id I need. I'm using jquery to retrieve the hidden textbox by the id. Jquery gets this Id from the second `input` attribute: `data-HiddenId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
@Html.TestBoxFor(
    model => model.Country.CountryName, 
    new { 
        data_hiddenid = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText((Expression<Func<ModelType, int>>)(x => x.Country.CountryId))
    }
)
```

and to reduce the ugliness you could write a custom HTML helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxWithIdFor<TModel, TProperty, TId>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TId>> idExpression
    )
    {
        var id = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(idExpression);
        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, new { data_hiddenid = id });
    }
}
```

and then simply:

```
@Html.TestBoxWithIdFor(
    model => model.Country.CountryName, 
    model => model.Country.CountryId
)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, is it also possible get just the final object of the expression? For eg. `CountryId`

Comment: @Lol coder, you already know it: `CountryId`. What more do you need?